# Your browser does not have flash, silverlight and html5 support

Tags: html, flash, silverlight, plugins

I want  to use PLupload plugin for uploading different files with different file extensions. But I get error "your browser does not have flash, Silverlight and Html5 support"
And I get no visual. I am using this [this plugin](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php)

Can I resolve this error??

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Yogiraj, hello!

Have you checked the "runtimes" option?
Maybe it's not set or it has only flash.

If possible, please, post your code.